# How to change file type association in Cornerstone svn

Tags: cornerstone

I have recently started using Cornerstone as an svn client.  I have yet to figure out how to change file extension associations.  In my case, it appears the default file type associated with a `.m` extension is objective C.

In my case these files should be associated with matlab files.  The cornerstone documentation appears pretty light, so does anybody have an idea how/where I can change this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Very well.  I removed the C flags.

Answer (score 0):

In Cornerstone, click on a file of the filetype you want to change. Then select the inspector (the i in the top right). Under the "Information" tab, if you scroll all the way to the bottom you should see an "Open With" option that you can configure.